# Reduce Array Of Managed Objects In Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble determining the syntax for reducing an array of a custom managed object subclass in Swift. I have a managed object subclass with a property called amount which is a NSNumber.  How do I use the reduce function to get the sum of amount for each item in the array of managed objects.  Here is what I have tried, but I get an error stating "could not find member 'amount'".

```
let reduceSum=myArray.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.amount}
```

I have looked at this [example](http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/06/25/understanding-swifts-reduce-method/), but it didn't help since I'm getting the could not find member error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right after posting this, I tried one more thing and it worked.  The error message was misleading and made me think the syntax was wrong but the real issue was I needed to convert the NSNumber to a CGFloat.  Here is what worked:

```
let reduceSum=myArray.reduce(0) {$0 + CGFloat($1.amount)}
```

Comment: Why does the that line not need `$0.amount`?

Comment: If you look at the example I cited in my question, that explains it better than I can.  From that link "In the reduce code, the first closure argument ($0) is the running total, which starts at zero, and the second parameter ($1) references a Person object in the people array."

Comment: But why do we need to cast it to a CGFloat? It works but why?